# How to Deserialize and Loop Json Array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, loops, serialization

I have json as such

```
{
    "TNS-API-KEY": "ABCD134EFG456HIJK678LMNOP",
    "docno": "35829",
    "idtns": "abc12345",
    "action": "6",
    "reason": "test -test",
    "userid": "450",
    "data": [
        {
        "pr": "0222\/ATL\/MIX\/01\/2021",
        "idpr": "13562",
        "cost": {
            "26217": {
                "50662": {
                    "costingid": "26217",
                    "costid": "50662",
                    "gpro": "SSM",
                    "dbp": "18000",
                    "ppn": "0"
                },
                "50664": {
                    "costingid": "26217",
                    "costid": "50664",
                    "gpro": "SBL",
                    "dbp": "40500",
                    "ppn": "0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "pr": "123\/AB\/MIX\/07\/2022",
            "idpr": "17461",
            "cost": {
                "34876": {
                    "66194": {
                        "costingid": "34876",
                        "costid": "66194",
                        "gpro": "CCL",
                        "dbp": "1000000",
                        "ppn": "110000.00"
                    }
                },
                "34877": {
                    "66195": {
                        "costingid": "34877",
                        "costid": "66195",
                        "gpro": "TB",
                        "dbp": "2000000",
                        "ppn": "220000.00"
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
       ]
    }
```

I need to get these data from each PR in the array

1. costingid
2. costid
3. gpro
4. dbp
5. ppn

So far I've manage to get until the data part using code like this

```
Dim jsonData As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim data As String = jsonData.SelectToken("data").ToString()
Dim jsonArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(jsonData.SelectToken("data").ToString)

For Each item As JObject In jsonArray
Dim pr As String = (item.SelectToken("pr").ToString)
Next
```

That snipped gives me the PR number, any idea how to get to the inside data?

There is also data where it has the same costing id, so any idea how to loop inside that too, since the costingid has no field name, so I don't know how to get that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get the values which you might want to dump in a list or something like that.

```
Dim prList As JArray = JObject.Parse(json)("data")
For Each pr As JObject In prList
    Dim prVal As String = pr("pr")
    For Each c As JProperty In pr("cost")
        For Each data As JObject In c.Value.Cast(Of JProperty).Select(Function(x) x.Value)
            Dim costingId As String = data("costingid")
            Dim costid As String = data("costid")
            Dim gpro As String = data("gpro")
            Dim dbp As String = data("dbp")
            Dim ppn As String = data("ppn")
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer turns out I found another combination in the json sent to me
there is also data that has costId but no costingId since that data came from the same costingId, any idea how to loop that too,

Your prev answer does help and works if there is no data that is like the current problem
Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo the costid and costingid come from different propeties and if costingid is not present it will return `Nothing`

Comment: Oh it's not that and it's okay, i actually modified the question a little bit and I got a bit stuck on when there is more than one costid under the same costingid can you help me?

Comment: The part i change is the first pr, now it is 0222\/ATL\/MIX\/01\/2021 that has one costingid which is 26217 and 2 costid 50662 and 50664, with your and answer, i only manage to get costingid 26217 with costid 50662 but it will not loop to the 50664, any idea for this one?